# gridview column width doesn't fits to the column contents

Tags: wpf, listview, datagrid

I have a `listview` and a `gridview` in it. I want the column header for one of my columns in `gridview` be empty, but the other columns have their headers. But when I set `header=""` for that `GridViewColumn`, the width of that column shrinks to fit the width of the header of the column that is empty, so the column becomes invisible. I tested `width="auto"` for the column but it doesn't work. How can I force this column sets its width according to the width of its cells, not its header?

the column that its header should be empty:

```
<GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn.Header>
        <GridViewColumnHeader Padding="2,2,2,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" ClickMode="Press" />
        </GridViewColumn.Header>
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Converter={StaticResource IndexConverter}}" FontWeight="Bold" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

the converter:

```
public class IndexConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type TargetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ListViewItem item = (ListViewItem)value;
        ListView listView = ItemsControl.ItemsControlFromItemContainer(item) as ListView;
        int index = listView.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(item) + 1;
        return index.ToString();
    }
    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture) { return new object(); }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Add some xaml here.

Comment: In a simple Example like `<GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Country}" />` the column has automatically the width of its contents! Also if `width="auto"` is set or `Header=""`. You should better start with simple examples or provide some code!

Answer (score 0):

it is the problem, that the column loads its contents after rendering. Then the initial auto width of the column isn't calculated again. So when your grid loads the header and cellcontents are empty. Then the initial width is calculated to zero.

You could use a simple trick to solve this issue by defining a `FallbackValue` for your Binding.

```
<GridViewColumn>
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, Converter={StaticResource IndexConverter}, FallbackValue='123'}" FontWeight="Bold" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>
```

Now your `ColumnWidth` is initially expanded to width of `123`.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I force this column sets its width according to the width of its cells, not its header?

The thing here is that the width of the `TextBlock` is not known until the binding has been resolved and by then the column has already been rendered.

What you could do work around this is to handle the `Loaded` event for the `TextBlock` and explicitly set the `Width` of the column. You could specify the index of the column to resize using the `Tag` property:

```
private void TextBlock_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TextBlock tb = sender as TextBlock;
    int index;
    if (tb != null && tb.Tag != null && int.TryParse(tb.Tag.ToString(), out index) && gv.Columns.Count > index)
    {
        gv.Columns[index].Width = tb.ActualWidth + 12;
    }
}
```

---

```
<ListView x:Name="lv">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <local:IndexConverter x:Key="IndexConverter" />
    </ListView.Resources>
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView x:Name="gv">
            <GridView.Columns>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.Header>
                        <GridViewColumnHeader Padding="2,2,2,0" VerticalContentAlignment="Bottom" ClickMode="Press" />
                    </GridViewColumn.Header>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}, 
                                        Converter={StaticResource IndexConverter}}" FontWeight="Bold" Tag="0" Loaded="TextBlock_Loaded" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView.Columns>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```